# FLEX: HTMLText paragraph tag adding extra line break

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

Alright, So I have an issue that is a bit weird. I am using a RichTextEditor and have allowed the user to re-size it. All the controls have been stripped away to a main toolbar such that the RichTextEditor just looks like a box with text in it. I have an issue where when I save the htmltext generated by the editor and then re-render it later it always adds an extra line break at the end of the text. I've found that this is due to the paragraph tag, and since I want the user to be able to align text I have to keep it. Does anyone know how to strip this last line break without stripping all the formatting?

Comment: Share some code?  Possibly a screenshot.

Comment: OK here's some screen shots: the first one shows the RTE before save the second one is after the user saved and then the htmltext was re-rendered [link](http://imgur.com/a/CCrxL)

Comment: So when you save the HTML text generated by the editor, it does **not** include the extra line break? But somehow gets added when you later set this saved text on the editor's `htmlText` property?

Comment: Not exactly, there never really is a line break in the htmltext, it is added when it is re-rendered by the closing paragraph tag. So the htmltext is the same either way.

`<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="36" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Fits Perfectly</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>`

Comment: From the screen shot, it seems like the problem is that on re-rendering the text it's deciding the text won't fit, and so it word wraps/add scrollbars. One way to confirm this, is on re-render try making the editor slightly larger and see if it renders properly. Another way: if the original text spans multiple lines (or has multiple paragraphs) is a line break then inserted between each line/paragraph on re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked a fix for this, basically involves stripping the last closing paragraph tag `</P>`. RichTextEditor is ugly :(

Comment: The only other fix may be to call the (possibly undocumented) function "getTextRuns" which returns character index ranges and their associated TextFormat instances. So if you were to serialize the plain text of the text field along with those TextRun instances, you could restore the content by assigning the plain text (which will not trigger that extra line), and then reapply the formatting specified in the TextRuns by calling setTextFormat( TextFormat, beginIndex, endIndex).  This would allow you to store the text separately, and would be fine for basic formatted content, but not links, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely a bug, and it is triggered by setting the "htmlText" property instead of the "text" property.  This occurs whether you assign it in code, or cause the designer to set "htmlText" instead of "text" by checking the "render as html" button in the properties for the text field.  Also of note, this only occurs on "input" type TextFields.  And if you start with a "dynamic" type textfield and subsequently set "type" to "input" (also have to set "selectable" to true or cursor will be invisible (another bug)), you will see the extra line appear right in front of your eyes.  Again, this does not effect dynamic text fields, just those in input mode.

Despite the fact that the htmlText property is identical in both cases whether you assign a string like "Hello" to text or htmlText (the htmlText value generated is identical for either), the extra line only appears when setting the htmlText property.

Specifically, it occurs when you set htmlText to a string that actually contains html paragraph tags.  If you just assign htmlText some text like "Hello", the problem will not occur.  On the other hand, if you assigned htmlText `<p>Hello</p>` or you assigned htmlText to itself (which you need to do to preserve the html and force the internal metrics to update immediately), then the problem occurs.  Someone mentioned, if you omit the closing `</p>` tag, the problem won't occur, and that's true.  It's also true that assigning something like `<a>Hello</a>` won't trigger the problem.

**So in summary, this problem occurs only when one sets the *htmlText* property of an *auto-sized*, *multiline*, *input* type text field to a value that contains `<p></p>` tags.**  It does not occur with dynamic text fields, nor does it occur on input text fields that are not autosized, nor does it occur on those who are autosized but not assigned `<p>` tags to htmlText.

To reproduce this problem, set up a text field in the designer and make sure the background and outline is turned on so you can see the size of the field, then it will be a single line  high (multiline text field) as expected (assuming it's wide enough).  If you then go to the code and set `txtfld.htmlText = txtfld.htmlText` (set it to itself), this mere assignment of htmlText property (to it's own same value) causes an additional line to be added.  And the value of htmlText is in fact the same, it hasn't actually snuck in an extra `<p>` tag or anything... it just displays this trailing return that shouldn't be there.  As expected, the same thing occurs when you check "render as html" in Flash properties for the text field, which  seems to cause it to set htmlText instead of text, and causes the problem to appear.

It's unlikely that there are actually two rendering modes, since it technically always renders htmlText (i.e. htmlText always has a value, and you could always set the text format of some segment of the text with setTextFormat, which was originally assigned with "text", and that doesn't trigger some kind of switch to "html rendering mode" or anything like that.

The behavior seems to strictly come as a result of assigning htmlText property.

The only way to avoid it (aside from setting htmlText, reading back the value, stripping the last `</p>` tag off, and reassigning it), is to just initialize all your text fields as plain "text", and then manually apply the formatting through calls to setTextFormat( TextFormat, beginIndex, endIndex).

The true catastophe of this bug, as mentioned in the original problem post, is that you cannot save and restore the htmlText value of a TextField, because setting htmlText to a string containing html (specifically the p tag), causes this extra line to be added, compounded by the fact that if you specifically want the textfield to be sized right, you'll probably have autosize turned on, and that's specifically when this problem creeps up and ensures the size is NOT right.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar headache with flex html text components. Flex does not have proper support for many html cases. You'll see extra padding for `<p>` and `<li>` all the time. Heck, there isn't even support for the `<ul>` tag. If there is a line break in a normal text, flex appends extra padding at the end of the tags and removing this line break will remove the extra padding.

However, you might want to use something like this: http://code.google.com/p/flex-htmlfilter/